# Require function does not work properly

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm using three php files in single php file because there three separated functions  so I included this files by using php's `require()` function. First, look at structure of my file

- Api
- Authentication

  - Controller.php
  - Loging.php
  - Signup.php
- Security

  - Controller.php

In `controller.php` of Authentication directory, I'll require `controller.php` file inside the Security directory so i just wrote code like this,

```
namespace AppAuthentication;

Require '../security/controller.php';
```

Now when executed the controller.php file of Authentication directory, it has generated this fatal error `require() : Failed to opening required...... No such file or directory. ...`

What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

When require, require_once, include, include_once and various other functions that access the file system, it's access relative to the file that was originally called. Now there's a simple way around this so that it's relative to the actual file you're doing the inclusion from, which is to use the magic constant of `__DIR__` which is the directory of the actual file it's placed in.

```
namespace AppAuthentication;

Require __DIR__ . '/../security/controller.php';
```